# ASP.NET ToList<> Cast bool to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code here:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.closed == false);
```

and this works great. I was wondering if it possible convert an item in my list from bool to string? something like

```
gv.DataSource = db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.closed == false).Cast(convert model.closed to string)
```

Comment: Project to a anonymous type

Comment: `db.Data.ToList().Where(model => !model.closed).Select(x => "true")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project your result to [anonymous type](http://v) and do the conversion there.

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = db.Data.ToList().Where(model => !model.closed)
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Closed = Convert.ToString(m.Closed),
        //... Rest of the fields. 
    });
```

Comment: Calling `ToList()` is unnecessary I fill and it can just be `db.Data.Where(model => !model.closed).Select(...`